# I am using ArrayAdapter with a List in a GridView. How can I configure to sort based on object variables from my ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, sorting, gridview, collections, android-arrayadapter

I am displaying an `ArrayAdapter` of objects MyBears in a `GridView` and I want to configure the order in which my objects from my `ArrayAdapter` are sorted in the `GridView`. 
I want to order the bears e.g. `new myBear(27, "Hi", 48)` based on the last parameter (in this case 48 - method is `myBear.getSize()`). How can I do this and where do I need to put this code. I tried to implement what I saw in other posts but none of them work.

Here is my xml where the grid appears:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_Bears"
    android:orientation="vertical”>
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/my_Bears_in_my_collection_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:griditem="@layout/one_my_Bear_in_my_collection_display" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is where I connect the array adapter with the grid.

```
public class MyCollectionFragment extends Fragment {


    private GridView mMyBearGridView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_collection,container,false);

        myBearsList = new ArrayList<>();
        mMyBearsAdapter = new MyBearsMyCollectionAdapter(this, R.layout.one_my_Bear_in_my_collection_display, myBearsList);
        mMyBearsAdapter.add(new myBear(27, "Hi", 48));
        mMyBearsAdapter.add(new myBear(4, "Hi", 87));
        mMyBearsAdapter.add(new myBear(6, "Hi", 39));
        mMyBearsAdapter.add(new myBear(8, "Hallo", 90));
        mMyBearsAdapter.add(new myBear(0, "Hi", 28));
        mMyBearsAdapter.add(new myBear(8, "Bye", 54));
        //the grid view from this fragment
        mMyBearGridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_Bears_in_my_collection_grid_view);
        mMyBearGridView.setAdapter(mMyBearsAdapter);

        return v;
    }

}
```

Here is my `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public class MyBearsMyCollectionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyBear> {
    private Context context;

    public MyBearsMyCollectionAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MyBear> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.one_my_Bear_in_my_collection_display, parent, false);
        }

        LinearLayout myBearsMyCollectionLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_Bear_linear_layout);
        ImageView myBearImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_Bear_image);

        final MyBear myBear = getItem(position);

        boolean isPhoto = myBear.getBearImageUrl() != null;
        if (isPhoto) {
            Glide.with(myBearImage.getContext())
                    .load(myBear.getBearImageUrl())
                    .into(myBearImage);
        }

        myBearsMyCollectionLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                BearPopup BearPopup = BearPopup.newInstance(myBear);
                FragmentManager manager = ((MainActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                BearPopup.show(manager, "BearPopup");
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm new to this, could you please explain me a bit more? Should this be in MyBear class itself? or somewhere else? and "sort it", where should i add it and using what method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am using a database and constantly adding objects in my ArrayAdapter, **1.** I need to add a sort Comparator in MyBear like this: 
    public static Comparator MyBearCreatedDateComparator
            = new Comparator() {

```
    public int compare(MyBear myBear1, MyBear myBear2) {

        Long MyBearCreatedDate1 = myBear1.getBearCreatedDate();
        Long MyBearCreatedDate2 = myBear2.getBearCreatedDate();

        return MyBearCreatedDate2.compareTo(MyBearCreatedDate1);
    }

};
```

**2.** And every time when i add a new object in my ArrayAdapter, I need to call a sort **3.** AND call the notifyDataSetChanged() so that my GridView/ListView refreshes. Like this:

```
mMyBearsAdapter.add(myBear);
                        mMyBearsAdapter.sort(MyBear.MyBearCreatedDateComparator);
                        mMyBearsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class MyBear implements Comparable<MyBear>{  

    private int size;

    @Override  
    public int compareTo(MyBear mBear) {  
        //Edited here with your get value
        int i = this.size - mBear.getSize();

        return i;  
    }  
}
```

Then add to your java code

```
    myBearsList = new ArrayList<>();
    myBearsList.add(new myBear(27, "Hi", 48));
    myBearsList.add(new myBear(4, "Hi", 87));
    myBearsList.add(new myBear(6, "Hi", 39));
    myBearsList.add(new myBear(8, "Hallo", 90));
    myBearsList.add(new myBear(0, "Hi", 28));
    myBearsList.add(new myBear(8, "Bye", 54));
    // edited here , add Collections
    Collections.sort(myBearsList);
    mMyBearsAdapter = new MyBearsMyCollectionAdapter(this, R.layout.one_my_Bear_in_my_collection_display, myBearsList);
```

**Note**

1. `public class MyBear implements Comparable<MyBear>{}`
2. use `compareTo` method
3. use `Collections.sort(myBearsList);`

Comment: thanks! I put Collections.sort(myBearsList); just after myBearsList = new ArrayList<>(); and before putting the list in the ArrayList in public class MyCollectionFragment extends Fragment, but my order still is not changing.  Do you know why? Should i put it in a different place?

Comment: Maybe this is where the tricky thing is. My add method is not on the ArrayList, but on the ArrayAdapter  mMyBearsAdapter.add(new myBear(8, "Bye", 54)); which i need to have i think if i want to display in a gridview. So I dont have ArrayList.add. What would you advise me to do in this case?

Comment: also i am curious, if I put Collections.sort(myBearsList); will it hold true also when i add later on other myBears in the ArrayAdapter? Or do i always need to resort manually, every time the arrayadapter changes (has one additional bear added)?

Comment: If you receive data from network or other way , you need to sort it again.It just liked the refresh the data.

Comment: Could I solve you question? And could you accept my answer? Good luck to you.@Emma

Comment: Unfortunately still not working. I need to use add method only on the arrayadapter, because i receive data from database and i constantly add data to the database, which automatically adds into this arrayadapter. The problem seems to be that i need to sort again everytime my arrayadapter changes. but the arraylist, i only put it once at the creation of the arrayadapter. So doing sorting on the arraylist just before initializing the arrayadapter, does not work. I also tried to look at how i can get to ArrayList when i am inside of the ArrayAdapter class, but cant find it.

Comment: because if i could find the ArrayList inside of the ArrayAdapter class, I could override the notifyDataSetChanged() method and add additionally to resort the arraylist. But there is no method to get the current arraylist...

Comment: there is also this method, sort(Comparator<? super T> comparator)
Sorts the content of this adapter using the specified comparator. but even when i put mMyBearsAdapter.sort(MyBear.MyBearSizeComparator), where the MyBearSizeComparator is created in MyBear class, it does not work.

Comment: I found the answer. Thanks KeLiuyue for helping me think further. Your answer would have worked i would i not have had constant adding of data from the database. Good luck further!!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in your **MyBear** pojo like this:

```
class MyBear implements Comparable<MyBear> {
   ... 
   int size;
   ...
   // Override compareTo method
   public int compareTo(MyBear myBear) {
     return this.size - myBear.getSize();
   }
   ...
}
```

Then sort it by using [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)):

```
Collections.sort(myBearsList);
```

Or you can use the lazy way by using `Collection.sort()` something like this:

```
Collections.sort(myBearsList, new Comparator<MyBear>() {
        @Override public int compare(MyBear o1, MyBear o2) {
          return NumberUtils.compare(o2.getSize(), o1.getSize());
        }
      });
```

This will sort the list with the biggest size first. You can reverse the sort by changing the comparison.